# React - How to Skip text passed in angular brackets from being parsed as html?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render html string. But the problem is that the some normal text may be enclosed between angular brackets. So, in that case it will be not be an html but will be parsed as an html and eventually stripped. I want that only valid html tags should be parsed as html and not the text enclosed in angular brackets.

Have tried passing the text in dangerouslySetInnerHTML but it strips out the text enclosed between angular brackets even if it is not an html. Have tried regex also for the same but it also does the same thing. Have tried rendering text using children in react but since it is a string it is being displayed as it is.

```
var sampleText = '<Hey There> Check this out! <b>WOW!</b>';
```

For the above `sampleText`,

"I expect the output to be `<Hey There> Check this out! WOW!` with WOW! in bold, but the actual output is `Check this out! WOW!` with WOW! in bold"

`<Hey There>` is being stripped when using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: Unless you implement preprocessing, the browser will either regard all `<..>` as tags or none. You would have to replace the "Hey There"-brackets with `&lt;` and `&gt;` manually (based on whether the content is part of a hardcoded list of tags), then set the text as `__html`.